# validate required fields are filled on modal with jquery

Tags: jquery, required

I am dynamically populate some text boxes in modal popup, when submitting the form I need to check required fields are filled.

I have tried with two method but both are not working..

If you want to check here is the full code 
http://jsfiddle.net/nsk21/f52nLfrj/

This how try 1:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#catSave', function(){
    var countValid = 0 ;
    totRequFileds = 0;

    $('#catCreatForm').find('input').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('type'));
        if(!$(this).prop('required')){
            if ( this.value.trim() !== '' ) {                           
                countValid++;                                           
            }else{      
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            }
            totRequFileds++; 
        } else {

        }
    });       
    alert(' totRequFileds:'+totRequFileds +' | '+countValid);
});
```

try 2:

```
      $( ':input[required]', '#catCreatForm' ).each( function () {
            alert($(this).attr('name'));
            if ( this.value.trim() !== '' ) {                           
                countValid++;                                           
            }else{      
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            }
            totRequFileds++; 
        });
```

Comment: You are dealing with Jquery and in you fiddle it doesn't included a libray

Comment: @underscore here is the updated version  http://jsfiddle.net/nsk21/f52nLfrj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have not comented out those lines in the fiddle, i have changed that lines a little

```js
$(document).on('click', '#catSave', function(){
 var countValid = 0 ;
 totRequFileds = 0;
 $( ':input[required]', '#catCreatForm' ).each( function () {
  totRequFileds++;
  alert($(this).attr('name'));
  if ( this.value.trim() !== '' ) {       
   countValid++;           
  }else{  
   $(this).focus();
   //return false;
  }
 });
 if( countValid != totRequFileds){
  alert('Please fill out all required fileds totRequFileds:'+totRequFileds +' | '+countValid);
      return false;
 }
    alert(' totRequFileds: '+totRequFileds +' | '+countValid);
});
```

Comment: its not working, it is only check the first text box only not all of the text boxes

Comment: what you did in your code is to check for each boxes at a time, and if a box is empty, then keep the focus on it and ends the check,,.. You can change its by removing the 'return false;' below '$(this).focus()'

Comment: i ll change it and show you by comenthing out the line